# Why overriding this core file "Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement.php" causes errors

Tags: php, magento, overriding, magento2

i wrote a simple module to override this core Model class, but on frontend it shows this error message:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to
>   Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ShippingAssignment\ShippingProcessor::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement,
>   instance of shipping\module\Model\ShippingMethodManagement\Interceptor
>   ....."

HERE IS MY 'di.xml' file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" type="shipping\module\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Need To Do :-**

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

**And Clean Cache**

Answer (score 0):

You need to run below commands after ensuring full permission:

```
chmod -R 777 var generated
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If error still persist, check if you are in developer mode by this command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

set in developer mode :

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

after setting to developer mode, remove var and generated folder,

```
rm -rf var generated
```

then flush cache :

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var generated
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend your class using the core path of the file as given below.

In **shipping\module\Model**

```
class ShippingMethodManagement extends 
Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement
{
   //You can write your custom functionality here
}
```

Don't forget to run the following commands after the change.

```
chmod -R 777 var generated
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

After added new Argument in constructor, need to re-created interpreter.So run di :compile command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```